# Leader board only getting displayed for testers

Tags: android, google-play, google-play-games

I have published a simple game with google game api.
All the code written have been taken from :
[Google tutorial](https://developers.google.com/games/services/android/leaderboards#updating_the_players_score)

and

[Stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23736137/onconnectionfailed-geving-sign-in-required)

But the problem is leaderboard is getting displayed only for testers and not for other users.

Link to my app :
[APP](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.naveen.naveenj.flappyball)

Comment: Have you  done alpha or Beta Publishing of your app? @nav_jain

Comment: Yes but now both alpha and beta testing is set to off.

Comment: Did you made it live last time,and has google approved it?@nav_jan

Comment: Yes it is available on play store as version 1.3.

Comment: I am able to install your app easily,Now there is no problem,I think the google takes some time to make the app live from alpha/beta publishing.Anyways nice app @nav_jan

Comment: Did you see the leaderboard screen in the end of the game? Game works fine for everyone. Ony problem is leaderboard screen is visible only to testers.

Comment: Which screen is the leaderboard screen,I didn't get it ,After the game is over I got a screen which shows game over,score-11,high score -22 double tap to start a new game.@nav_jan

Comment: Ideally you should get a screen shown in : https://developers.google.com/games/services/android/leaderboards#displaying_a_leaderboard all my testers get this screen but not other users.

Comment: As I can see your app has gone live yesterday,generally it takes 1-2 days to go live so that users can see the full functionality.In that case I request you to wait for tomorrow and wait for the result.@nav_jan

Comment: Hi nav_jan just got your Leaderboard screen after the game is over.@nav_jan

Comment: Thanks, I think issue might have been due to delay as you said in your previous comment.

Comment: Welcome nav_jan enjoy happy coding :).Please upvote my other answers if you find them helpful.Thanks again@nav_jan