# How to Resolve SIGN_IN_REQUIRED error in google plus integration?

Tags: android

I have an app in which i have implemented google+ sign in. I have checked all the code and found after dubugging it is always throws an error in onConnectionFailed(ConnectionResult result) where result is shown as follow:

```
ConnectionResult{statusCode=SIGN_IN_REQUIRED, resolution=PendingIntent{425b8550: android.os.BinderProxy@423ec2e8}, message=null}
```

code:-

```
mGoogleApiClient = buildGoogleAPIClient();
gPlusLoginButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            processGPlusSignIn();
        }
    });


 private void processGPlusSignIn() {
    if (!mGoogleApiClient.isConnecting()) {
        Log.e("", "GPLUS area 111");
        startExecutingGPlusLoginProcess();
        mSignInClicked = true;
    }

}
private void startExecutingGPlusLoginProcess() {
    if (mConnectionResult != null && mConnectionResult.hasResolution()) {
        try {
            mIntentInProgress = true;
            Log.i("Registration", "Starting...");
            mConnectionResult.startResolutionForResult(this, GPLUS_SIGN_IN_REQUEST_CODE);
        } catch (IntentSender.SendIntentException e) {
            Log.e("Registartion", "Exception***" + e);
            mIntentInProgress = false;
            mGoogleApiClient.connect();
        }
    }
}
@Override
public void onConnectionFailed(ConnectionResult connectionResult) {
    Log.e(TAG,"onConnectionFailed called");

    if (!connectionResult.hasResolution()) {
        GooglePlayServicesUtil.getErrorDialog(connectionResult.getErrorCode(), this, ERROR_DIALOG_REQUEST_CODE).show();
        return;
    }
    if (!mIntentInProgress) {
        mConnectionResult = connectionResult;
        Log.e("Registration", "Result?***" + connectionResult);
        if (mSignInClicked) {
            startExecutingGPlusLoginProcess();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23736137/onconnectionfailed-giving-sign-in-required4

Answer (score 0):

You may try the below code :
first you need to initalize GoogleApi like that:

```
private void googleInitialization() {
    GoogleSignInOptions gso = new GoogleSignInOptions.Builder(GoogleSignInOptions.DEFAULT_SIGN_IN)
            .requestEmail()
            .build();
    mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
            .enableAutoManage(this, this)
            .addApi(Auth.GOOGLE_SIGN_IN_API, gso)
            .build();
    mGoogleApiClient.connect();


}
```

After that you need to call this method like that:-

```
googleInitialization();
                    Intent signInIntent = Auth.GoogleSignInApi.getSignInIntent(mGoogleApiClient);
                    startActivityForResult(signInIntent, RC_SIGN_IN);
```

and thid handle in OnActivityResult there is a **CallBackManager** which is very useful to call the login button

```
  @Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        callbackManager.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

        if (requestCode == RC_SIGN_IN) {
            GoogleSignInResult result = Auth.GoogleSignInApi.getSignInResultFromIntent(data);
            handleSignInResult(result);
        }
    }
```

Now, Get result in the below method:

```
 private void handleSignInResult(GoogleSignInResult result) {
        Log.d("handleSignInResult", "handleSignInResult:" + result.isSuccess());
        if (result.isSuccess()) {
            // Signed in successfully, show authenticated UI.
            GoogleSignInAccount acct = result.getSignInAccount();
            String personName = acct.getDisplayName();
            String email = acct.getEmail();
            if (personName.contains(" ")) {
              String  fname = personName.substring(0, personName.lastIndexOf(" ") + 1);
             String     lname = personName.substring(personName.lastIndexOf(" ") + 1);
                Log.e("First name", fname);
                Log.e("Last name", lname);
            } else
              String    fname = personName;

            Log.e("Profile Info", "Name: " + personName + ", email: " + email);
        }
    }
```